# Default R output with a command line parameter

Tags: r, output, rscript

I am trying to provide a way of running unattended R scripts through Rscript. The problem I am having is that the default output for graphics is a PDF file in the *current* directory. I would like to redirect this output to a separate folder but without having to change the script too much.

If my script is something simple as:

```
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

mydata <- get some data frame somehow
plot(tayside)
```

And I execute the following commandline:

```
Rscript.exe --vanilla --default-packages=RODBC,graphics,grDevices sample.R > C:\temp\sample.Rout
```

I get a `Rplots.pdf` in the current folder and the `sample.Rout` file in the `C:\temp\` folder.

Is there a way to specify an output folder and have Rscript put all output there? I have tried playing with the `pdf.options(...)` to pre-pend a default folder to the `file` parameter but no can do.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, apparently it was easier than I thought, no need to use `pdf.options()` but simply `pdf()` at the top of the file (after getting the arguments):

```
pdf(paste0(args[1], "MyFile.pdf"))
```

or, for multiple files:

```
pdf(paste0(args[1], "MyFile%03d.pdf"), onefile=FALSE)
```